# R - save multiplot to file

Tags: r, save, ggplot2

I’d really appreciate your help with the following problem. I know several ways to save a single plot to a file. My question is: How do I correctly save a **multiplot** to a file?

To begin with, I’m not an experienced R user. I use ggplot2 to create my plots, and another thing I should probably mention is that I use the RStudio GUI. Using an [example](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20%28ggplot2%29/)  from the R Cookbook, I'm able to create multiple plots in one window.

I would like to save this so-called multiplot to a file (preferably as jpeg), but somehow fail to do this.

I’m creating the multiplot as follows:

```
##define multiplot function
    multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, cols) {
        require(grid)

        # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
        plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

        numPlots = length(plots)

        # Make the panel
        plotCols = cols                          # Number of columns of plots
        plotRows = ceiling(numPlots/plotCols) # Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols

        # Set up the page
        grid.newpage()
        pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(plotRows, plotCols)))
        vplayout <- function(x, y)
            viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

        # Make each plot, in the correct location
        for (i in 1:numPlots) {
            curRow = ceiling(i/plotCols)
            curCol = (i-1) %% plotCols + 1
            print(plots[[i]], vp = vplayout(curRow, curCol ))
        }

    }

## define subplots (short example here, I specified some more aesthetics in my script)
plot1a <- qplot(variable1,variable2,data=Mydataframe1)
plot1b <- qplot(variable1,variable3,data=Mydataframe1)  
plot1c <- qplot(variable1,variable2,data=Mydataframe2)
plot1d <- qplot(variable1,variable3,data=Mydataframe2)  

## plot in one frame
Myplot <- multiplot(plot1a,plot1b,plot1c,plot1d, cols=2)
```

This gives the desired result. The problem arises when I try to save to a file. I can do this manually in RStudio (using Export -> Save plot as image), but I would like to run everything in a script. I manage to save only subplot1d (which is last_plot()), and not the complete multiplot.

What I’ve tried so far:

1. Using ggsave

   ```
   ggsave(filename = "D:/R/plots/Myplots.jpg")
   ```

   This results in only subplot 1d being saved.
2. Using jpeg(), print() and dev.off()

   ```
   jpeg(filename = "Myplot.jpg", pointsize =12, quality = 200, bg = "white", res = NA, restoreConsole = TRUE)
   print(Myplot)
   dev.off()
   ```

   This results in a completely white image (just the background I assume). print(Myplot) returns NULL.

Not sure what I’m doing wrong here. My lack of understanding R is the reason I am stuck trying to find a solution. Can anyone explain what I’m doing wrong and perhaps suggest a way to solve my problem(s)?

Comment: You can also use **gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot1a,plot1b,plot1c,plot1d, ncol = 2)**

Comment: The gridExtra package does not contain grid.arrange, it does contain arrangeGrob which seems to provide the same functionality. I also seem to remember a function called grid.arrange, maybe the author changed the function titles in the package.

Comment: `grid.arrange` should be in gridExtra. Incidently, one of the benefits of `arrangeGrob` vs `multiplot` is that it's compatible with `ggsave`, and that you can store the composite grob for later use.

Comment: I just want to mention that jpeg is probably not the best choice.  If the plot should end up as a raster image (and not e.g. pdf or eps), use png instead.  It uses lossless compression, i.e. there will be no artifacts around sharp contrast regions such as text or lines.  Its compression also works great for images with large areas of one single color, such as plots.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its because `Myplot` is the returned value from your multiplot function, and it returns nothing (its job is to print the graphs). You need to call multiplot with the jpeg device open:

```
jpeg(filename = "Myplot.jpg", pointsize =12, quality = 200, bg = "white", res = NA, restoreConsole = TRUE)
multiplot(plot1a,plot1b,plot1c,plot1d, cols=2)
dev.off()
```

should work.

Comment: It really is that simple! Thanks a lot for explaining why my approach did not work.

Answer (score 19):

Using the [example code](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20%28ggplot2%29/) (R cookbook), it works for me

```
png("chickweight.png")
multiplot(p1, p2, p3, p4, cols=2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, but your code is slightly different from @M_Vermeulen, she first plots the 4 plots, expecting `multiplot` to return a grid object. It could be that `grid.arrange` does show this behavior?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: I don't think that I took a different approach here, take a look at the example page. The real problem was explained by @Spacedman very well. And yes `grid.arrange` show the same behavior

Comment: Your code already incorporates the fix of @Spacedman, the multiplot needs to be inside the call `png`.

Comment: Anyway to increase size of each plot?

Answer (score 7):

And for completeness sake, `ggsave` does not work as it only saves the last printed ggplot object, which in your case is just the last plot. This is caused by the fact that multiplot creates the plot by drawing the ggplot objects onto different subsets of the total graphics device. An alternative is to create the plot by combining the ggplot objects into one big ggplot object, and then printing the object. This would be compatible with `ggsave`. This approach is implemented by `arrangeGrob` in the `gridExtra` package.

Comment: technically, `arrangeGrob` doesn't create "one big ggplot object", it returns a gTree of class "arrange", and if there are ggplots in the list of children, then the class also inherits from "ggplot" to fool ggsave.